# When to use a comma before "and"

Tags: commas, conjunctions, oxford-comma

I often see people on the Internet using a comma before *and* in many cases (not adversative cases). Is it ok? In my language it is stricly prohibited to use a comma before an *and* except for adversative cases or when an apposition is in the front of that *and*.

Examples (which I consider **not ok**):

> He is a great player, and he prefers to play *Counter-Strike*.
>
> John joined the Army, and George joined the Marines.

What I consider exceptions:

> Yes, and what is the problem?
>
> I called John, my brother, and now I’m speaking with him.

Comment: Similar to [Comma before "and"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/42811).  Also see [Usage of a comma before "and" in a fairly complex sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/117410), or [Why is there no comma before AND?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/118085), or [Using a comma before "but"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28277), or [Should I use a comma before "and" or "or"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30516), but not [Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/412).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the adversative case, and a Google search doensn't turn up a simple definition – I don't think it's a feature of English. In any case, all of those commas are fine; please see my answer for an analysis of each sentence.

Comment: @BraddSzonye, not ‘adversative case’ as a grammatical term, but ‘in contexts where ‘and’ has an adversative meaning’.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50111/when-does-a-comma-change-the-meaning-of-a-sentence/51296#51296

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Could you give an example? I can't think of a case off the top of my head where _and_ is adversative; that role is usually filled by _but._

Comment: @BraddSzonye, in “John joined the army, and George joined the Marines”, ‘and’ has a somewhat adversative role. I assume in Romanian (or whatever Radu’s native language is) this role is termed an _adversative ‘and’_, or that ‘and’ can be used in a more directly adversative manner there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Oxford Guide to Style 2nd ed section 5.3:

Use the comma to join main clauses that are semantically related,
grammatically similar, and linked by one of the coordinating conjunctions
*and*, *but*, *nor*, *or*, and *yet*. Such clauses are joined by a comma if they
are too long, and too distinct in meaning, to do without any punctuation
at all, but not separate enough to warrant a semi-colon:

> Truth ennobles man, and learning adorns him.
>
> Cars will turn here, but coaches will go straight on.
>
> I will not try now, yet it is possible I may try again in future.

It may be omitted when the clauses are short and closely linked:

> Do as I tell you and you'll never regret it.
>
> Dan left but Jill remained.
>
> I will not try now yet I may in future.

Answer (score 3):

All four of your examples are [compound sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_sentence), which permit linking commas:

> A compound sentence is composed of at least two independent clauses. . . . **The clauses are joined by a coordinating conjunction (with or without a comma),** a correlative conjunction (with or without a comma), a semicolon that functions as a conjunction, a colon instead of a semicolon between two sentences when the second sentence explains or illustrates the first sentence and no coordinating conjunction is being used to connect the sentences, or a conjunctive adverb preceded by a semicolon.

As **@aurora** notes, we commonly use commas with coordinating conjunctions except when linking very short and closely-related clauses, and even then it's never *incorrect* to use the comma. Here's how your sentences parse, with some additional notes.

> **Clause 1:** He is a great player.
>   **Clause 2:** He prefers to play *Counter-Strike*.
>   **Compound:** He is a great player, and he prefers to play *Counter-Strike.*

Because both clauses have the same subject, you could could naturally replace *and he* with a relative pronoun: “He is a great player who prefers to play *Counter-Strike,*” making it a complex sentence instead of a compound.

> **Clause 1:** John joined the Army.
>   **Clause 2:** George joined the Marines.
>   **Compound:** John joined the Army, and George joined the Marines.

This is a straightforward example of a compound sentence. Because both clauses are short and similar, you could omit the comma if you prefer.

> **Clause 1:** Yes.
>   **Clause 2:** What is the problem?
>   **Compound:** Yes, and what is the problem?

Here, *Yes* is a special kind of clause called a [*pro-sentence.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-sentence)

> **Clause 1:** I called John, my brother.
>   **Clause 2:** Now I'm speaking with him.
>   **Compound:** I called John, my brother, and now I’m speaking with him.

In this case, the phrase *my brother* is in apposition, so it must be set off with commas regardless of the structure of the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

English doesn't have any *formal or official rules*, so nothing can be *prohibited* at all, certainly not *strictly prohibited*.  It does, of course, have generally accepted modes of usage, which may be considered as informal rules - but the important thing is that the 'rules' are determined by usage, and not *vice versa*.

The issue in determining comma usage is whether the presence of a comma helps to break up a long sentence, whether it helps the reader in understanding the sentence, whether it helps to indicate a natural pause in the sentence.

The only one of your sentences that *I* would change is the first:

> He is a great player and prefers to play Counter-Strike™.

(I have been informed that "Counter-Strike" is a Trade Mark and should therefore be capitalised. I have no information as to whether it is registered in any country.)

Note that I also omitted "he". Having said that, there is *nothing wrong* with your original version, just that the second version may sound more natural to a fluent speaker.

You should also look at the other questions links from the comments. Although several of them may relate to lists, they may still have useful explanations about comma usage.

Comment: Counter-Strike is a trademark of Valve Corporation; as such, it must be capitalised.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet OK - no indication of that in the question. In that case, it should also be acknowledged as a TM. In the absence of any indication to the contrary, I had assumed it was a position that the person preferred to play in some type of ball game, possibly Am. Football (about which i know absolutely nothing!). If (as I'm now assuming) Counter-Strike is some kind of video game, then the original sentence doesn't make much sense to me: "He's a great player" of/at what? - clearly not solely referring to a single game as I first assumed.

Comment: I think the intended meaning of “great player” here is “avid gamer”. Whether to add ™ or ® after trademarks is a style guide issue; for example, the [Wikipedia style guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style_(trademarks)) specifies that nothing should be appended unless strictly necessary.

Comment: I'll accept that for unregistered TMs, but the owners of registered TMs may well disagree. As a former Patent & TM Attorney (tho' I did little on TMs), I would attempt always to acknowledge registered TMs; those misusing them can be sued; and it could be argued that acknowledging their legal status when using them is "strictly necessary".

Comment: Oh, also: Radu wrote that in _his language_ (which I presume to be Romanian) the commas were strictly prohibited; not that they are in English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes - and he also asked (reworded) is the 'loose' usage he was referring to OK in English, because he is used to there being strict rules. I replied accordingly, that English doesn't have strict rules (like his language does) and so no comma usage can be prohibited (in the way it is in his language). What point are you making?

Comment: I have to admit that I too thought "Counter Strike" was a position played in Am football (it is not a popular sport in Italy). As for the TM mark I think that's an unrealistic request. Maybe a parenthetical comment was all that was needed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If one knows enough to know that it ought to be capitalised, then one ought to know it should be acknowledged, but you're right that that could be done in a footnote or endnote particularly if the TM is used frequently. There is no *legal* requirement, but *registered* TM owners can be vigilant in policing use of their marks. Some famous registered marks (e.g. Monopoly (TM) in some countries) have been 'lost' (deregistered) because their use became generic (rather than unique to the product). So mark owners like to ensure the link is retained by enforcing acknowledgement.

Comment: @TrevorD who knew that the word Monopoly(TM) was registered?! I learn something new everyday. Might I get a ticking off for writing "iPad" online without the TM symbol?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Good point. I guess there comes a point where a mark becomes so famous that it need not be acknowledged! There are no rules about it, but my former profession taught me to be vigilant on the issue! Ultimately, it's up to TM owners to protect their rights. I'm sure that if Apple™ saw *iPad™* being used as a generic term for tablets or in reference to a product that was not their own, they would probably come down down on the user like a ton(ne) of bricks!

Comment: I was just going to ask about the superscript TM... I tried. Guess I have to copy and paste

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think this should be standard on all PC (not Apple™) keyboards (but I'm using a UK one). With NumLock ON, hold down Alt & press 0153 on the *Numeric* Keypad (which may be embedded in the main keypad on a laptop or smaller keyboard). Do NOT use the numbers in the top row. For character lists see http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codealt.html; http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/ALTchrc.html; http://www.forlang.wsu.edu/help/keyboards.asp; and many others.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No. Alt+0153 will produce ™ wherever the cursor currently is. I believe that these 'Alt codes' are universal and not affected by keyboard layout. E.g. Alt+0225 = á; Alt+0191 = ¿. Have a look at the links I gave.

Comment: I wouldn't definitely say English is lacking rules. Surely there are some basic rules, if not strictly formal at least informal?

Comment: @aurora I was, of course, responding specifically to the issue of things being "prohibited" as mentioned in the question. But I've revised and augmented my answer in that respect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As others have written, comma usage is not required in some scenarios; commas should be used in **compound sentences**, where there are two independent clauses being combined, but **they are optional in [coordinating conjunctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjunction#Coordinating_conjunctions)** ([Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)).  A quick [Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?%7Bgoogle%3aacceptedSuggestion%7Doq=compound%20sentence&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=compound%20sentence&qscrl=1) reveals this information.

In other scenarios, we may or may not opt to use the [Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).  The most important thing is that the writing is *consistent*; writing that includes coordinating conjunctions both using and not using the extra comma can confuse the reader.  It is important to research the format you are writing in, as different writing styles may or may not mandate the usage of the Oxford comma.  For example, the Chicago Manual Style requires the Oxford comma while the Canadian Press forbids it.

As you guessed correctly, there are some exceptions to where commas must be placed.  For a more detailed summary, [view the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma).

Answer (score -1):

A programming manual describing the logical operator 'AND' would have a comma before that word and be grammatically correct.  I know it's a cheeky answer, but it's an answer :).

> Digital Logic operators include OR, AND, XOR, and others.

Comment: It doesn’t answer the question, though, which was about commas _before_ ‘and’, not after it.

Comment: Digital Logic operators include OR, AND, XOR, and others.

Comment: It is difficult to note the comma *before* the small "and" in defence of @JanusBahsJacquet, if you could edit your answer in such a way as to make the comma position more noticeable then the downvote might be reversed.

Comment: Sorry but this is sort of wrong but coincidentally also correct. "AND" (uppercase) is in this case just a name or label for a logical operation and not a linguistic conjunction as such, so the comma in front of AND is there because of the enumeration. But your answer is correct because of the lowercase "and" between XOR and "others", which has a comma.